# Редактирование элемента структуры c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, struct

Вот структура которая состоит из имени и возраста человека. Как изменить имя и возраст н-ого человека в структуре? И вывести уже измененную структуру на экран.

```
public struct persons
        {
            public string name;
            public int age;

            public persons(string _name, int _age) : this()
            {
                this.name = _name;
                this.age = _age;
            }

        }
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         
            List<persons> person = new List<persons>();
            int m = 4;
            
            for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
            {
                string onePerson = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                string[] wrPerson = onePerson.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                person.Add(new persons(wrPerson[0], Convert.ToInt32(wrPerson[1])));
            }
            for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
            {
                WriteLine(person[i].name + " " + person[i].age);
            }
        int n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Comment: Забудьте вы про структуру! А еще лучше, замените ее на класс, ибо вам структура вообще не сдалась тут, только путает вас, новичка. `н-ого человека в структуре` - вот у вас есть корзина с яблоками, по вашей логике, вы внутри яблока хотите заменить у н-го яблока его свойство. Так может не внутри яблока, а внутри корзинки? Вот у вас корзинка `List<persons> person = new List<persons>();`, только имена вы перепутали, ибо между `<..>` вы указываете ТИП ОДНОГО ОБЪЕКТА `<яблоко>`, а название корзинки, уже да `яблоки`, то есть `List<person> persons...`. Ну а дальше, по индексам обращаться вы умеете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384290/373567 похоже, дело плохо. Человек не понял примерно ничего из моего ответа.

Comment: Я все понял, в прошлый раз, и очень Вам благодарен за помощь, тогда я реально затупил. Сейчас я задал другой вопрос. Редактирование и удаление это разные вещи. В прошлый раз мне писали что-то типа person[n]="вася" - это не работает. И мне нужна именно структура. Я не нашел информации на эту тему в интернете и поэтому пришел сюда задать вопрос

Comment: @aepot вообще, Вы предлагаете как раз ошибочный вариант. Из списка по индексу возвращает копия структуры, так что изменение его поля ни к чему не приведёт. В последних компиляторах такой код (`person[n].name = "Вася"`) вернёт явную ошибку. На такую ошибку видимо и напоролся Алексей, и не знает, что с неё делать.

Comment: @Алексей В случае списка структур - только перезапись объекта. Либо по нужному индексу создаёшь новый объект: `person[n] = new persons(person[n], 30);` - тут перезаписывается структура с сохранением имени. Либо копируешь в локальную переменную: `var temp = person[n]; temp.age = 30; person[n] = temp;` - тут сначала идёт копирование в локальную переменную, там она модифицируется и обратно копируешь в список. Но вообще говоря, изменяемые структуры - это хрень. И лучше так лишний раз так не делать - меньше проблем.

Comment: @John вы правы, всё верно. Жаль что не массив, можно было бы ref. Структуры изменяемые по этой самой причине не использую, забылось.